# Source of travel funds when applying for a UK visa as a married couple

Tags: visas, uk, money, proof-of-funds

Can someone suggest if me & my husband both are travelling to UK for vacation and paying for our share of expenses like half & half...What should I fill in my visa application for  'Cost anyone else is paying for all or part of your trip'. I selected 'No' as I will paying for myself and he will be paying for himself.

Is it correct ?

Also, India & The Bahamas are commonwealth countries...correct ?

Comment: If playing it strictly by the book, you need to tell us if the bank accounts are fully segregated and their funding streams are also segregated.  Please edit.

Comment: It is as we both are working professionals. We want Visa officers to see our applications as separate entity even though we are going as a family :)

Comment: Btw, I am thinking to mentioned same thing under 'Additional Information' as we both are working and have separate funds...and paying separate. Would it work ?

Comment: Yes, that's fine

Comment: [Google will tell you what are the commonwealth countries.](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=commonwealth+countries)

Answer (score 1):

Each person should file a separate application that refers to their own accounts.  Both can use Part 9 of the application to show that the applications are linked and that each applicant is using their own funds.

For your other question: India and The Bahamas are both Commonwealth members.